# Azure Function Application Failing on PostgreSQL pg Call

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I am attempting to emulate the example on writing to PostgreSQL from the Azure IoT Hub as outlined [in this example.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-postgresql/tree/master/samples/IoT%20Demo)

I've managed to set everything up correctly to where the Function is getting triggered. However, the code supplied in the article:

```
    module.exports = async function (context, IoTHubMessages) {
    var pg = require('pg');
    //const config = "postgres://<username>:<password>@<postgres servername>:5432/<database>";
    
    const config = {
                        host: 'myserver.postgres.database.azure.com',
                        user: 'granted@myserver',     
                        password: 'password',
                        database: 'telemetry',
                        port: 5432,
                        ssl: true
    };
    
    var client = new pg.Client(config);
    const query = 'insert into tempdata(deviceid, data) values(' + eventHubMessages.deviceId + ',\'' + JSON.stringify(eventHubMessages) + '\');';
    context.log(query);
    client.connect();
    client.query(query);
    await client.end();
    context.log('insert completed successfully!');  
    /*
    client.connect(err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
            client
                .query(query)
                .then(() => {
                context.log('insert completed successfully!');
                client.end(console.log('Closed client connection'));
                 })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
            .then(() => {
                context.log('Finished execution, exiting now');
                        });
            }
        });
        */
};
```

Generates this error:

> Result: Failure Exception: Cannot find module 'pg' Require stack: -
> /home/site/wwwroot/IoTHub_EventHub2/index.js

I assume I have to get PostgreSQL installed within the function or something? Any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was attempting to install and run the Function from the portal. There is no way to add dependencies, such as PostgreSQL, through that mechanism. Setting up a project in Visual Studio Code, I was able to run npm locally which then added the dependencies to the project and when I installed the function. That fixed this problem.